# Remove Colourful indentation from vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new in vscode and unknowingly I changed my vscode settings, after that when I started coding the indentation has a colorful indentation. How do I revert this back to the default indentation style?

[image: In this image the indentation is colourful, and i want to remove this colourfull indentation and want default indentation]

Comment: That is one of your extensions doing that - vscode doesn't do that.  You have some bracket highlighter thingt?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a default behavior defined by vscode. Perhaps it's one of your extensions, It looks like you at least have the prettier extension installed.

You could use the search feature in the Settings menu to search both vscode settings and installed extension settings:

1. Open Settings `Ctrl + ,` or `File -> Preferences -> Settings`
2. Type in the search bar at the top.